# length and precision issue in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, ddl, sqldatatypes

I'm using postgres sql I need 12 digits and after decimal I need only 6 digits what length & Precision should I give in columns.what datatype shold I give to cloumn.

I tried numeric as a datatype and length I give to column is 12 and precision is 6.

Comment: And what happened when you tried that? I assume it didn’t work, but what was the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need 12 digits *before* the decimal and 6 digits after, you need `numeric(18,6)`

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL)

> The scale of a numeric is the count of decimal digits in the fractional part, to the right of the decimal point. The precision of a numeric is the **total count** of significant digits in the **whole number**, that is, the number of digits to **both sides** of the decimal point

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

So the first number (precision) in the type definition is the **total number** of digits. The second one is the number of decimal digits.

If you specify `numeric(12,6)` you have a *total* of 12 digits and 6 decimal digits, which leaves you only 6 digits for the digits to the left of the decimal. Therefor you need `numeric(18,6)`